# Geoserver - roles from open id connect fails

Tags: geoserver, authentication

We can't get any roles from userinfo endpoint when we use openid connect (oidc) with GeoServer. It seems that GeoServer gets the principal key correctly but not the roles. We need to match roles from oidc with groups/roles from LDAP so we can utilise the correct getCapabilities for the user in our application.

We can't figured out why this doesn't work.

Below are the settings for oidc, geoserver oidc connection and message from log.

The userinfo endpoint from the provider:

```
{
   "role" [
      "GROUP_A",
      "GROUP_B",
      "GROUP_C"
    ],
   "mail": "name@xxx.com",
   "samaccountname": "user_a"
}
```

Settings in GeoServer openid connect provider connection:

[image]

We get this message in geoserver.log:

```
Authenticated OAuth request for principal user_a
DEBUG [geoserver.security]-preAuthenticatedPrincipal=user_a, trying to authenticate
DEBUG [geoserver.security]-Did not find rolein the token, returning an empty role list
```

We are using GeoServer 2.20.2 with recently updated oidc-files. We added the oidc-connection at the top of each filter chain (web, rest, gwc and default).

How can we get GeoServer to read the roles from userinfo endpoint?

Comment: From the looks of it you have configured the Access token as role source. Can it be that the access token does not contain the role claim? Log excerpts indicates that.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Stefan, there are no roles when we decode the access token. So the role claim should be in the token and the principalname in userinfo endpoint? The testfiles on github indicates that roles should be in userinfo. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: I have never tried the OIDC plugin myself but if you configure the role source to be "Access Token" I would expect that roles should be in access token. So then it's up to your Idp if it adds those claims in the access token. To request the the roles claim to be included in the access token you may need to add a Scope that includes the roles claims. You only specify "openid" in the Scopes box.